# Why is this query not supported in linq to entities?

Tags: linq-to-entities

I have a query like so.

```
var query = from o in _context.Orders
            join c in _context.Customers on o.CustomerId equals c.CustomerId
            orderby o.ShippedDate descending
            select new {OrderId = o.OrderId, Customer = c.FirstName};
```

I get the error "Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported".  I swear I have been able to do this before but for the life of me can't understand what the issue is.  I also can't restructure the query like this either.

```
var query = from o in _context.Orders
            orderby o.ShippedDate descending
            select new {OrderId = o.OrderId, Customer = o.Customer.FirstName};
```

Baffled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query = from o in _context.Orders
            join c in _context.Customers on o.CustomerId equals c.CustomerId
            orderby o.ShippedDate descending
            select new {o.OrderId, c.FirstName};
```

Comment: Still the same error.  The funny thing is that as soon as I call "ToList() or ToArray(). I can query on that group and use navigation properties to my hearts content.

Comment: @nameEqualsPNamePrubeGoldberg, on which line are you getting the error?

Comment: The last one.  'The specified type "FirstName" is not supported in linq to entities' ....

Answer (score 0):

Try something like...

```
 var query = from o in _context.Orders
             join c in _context.Customers on o.CustomerId equals c.CustomerId
             orderby o.ShippedDate descending
             let OrderID = o.OrderID
             let Customer = c.FirstName
             select OrderID, Customer
```